# What is known about 'direct sums' of games?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Here a game is a two player, alternating turn where the loser is the first player to have no moves. Also suppose that we have a notion of consecutive moves, where it is possible for a player to continue playing the game if their opponent passes (basically all board games satisfy these requirements)

Then we have a notion of the disjoin sum of two games. Basically imagine having two boards and players take turns playing on one board at a time, their choice of which board. The loser is the first with no moves on any board.

What is known about the value/solution of such a game in terms of the component games? I know the answer is quite complicated, even for simple games, but what work has been done?

Comment: This is a major topic of [combinatorial game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory). Here is one basic result. Let $G$ and $H$ be games obeying some suitable conditions, including that the winner is whoever makes the last legal move. Let $G+H$ denote the direct sum game. Further suppose $G$ is a win for whichever player goes second (under optimal play). Then the outcome of $G+H$ is the same as $H$ (under optimal play).

Comment: Isn't that just the "nim sum"?

Comment: You should track down the book "Winning Ways For Your Mathematical Plays" because first, it has a lot of answers to your question, and second, because it is absolutely delightful.

Comment: This is extremely broad. Some basics of what is known is covered across almost the entire undergraduate textbooks of [An Introduction to Combinatorial Game Theory](https://www.lulu.com/en/ca/shop/l-r-haff-and-w-j-garner/an-introduction-to-combinatorial-game-theory/hardcover/product-23626072.html) and [Lessons in Play: An Introduction to Combinatorial Game Theory](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/lessonsinplay/) and over half (arguably nearly all) of the graduate textbook [Combinatorial Game Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-146/). And much more is known beyond the scope of those books, as well.